# Imagemagick place image in bottom right corner

Tags: php, html, css, watermark

I used the imagemagic to place the watermark image. I used the following code to display the watermark in center.

```
shell_exec("composite -gravity center logo.png images/test.png images/test.png");
```

Now I want to display the watermark in bottom right corner.

For this i tried the code:

```
composite -geometry -10-10
```

But i couldn't display this in bottom right.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
shell_exec("composite -gravity SouthEast logo.png images/test.png images/test.png");
```

Answer (score -1):

Use for Bottom Right Corner:

imagecopyresampled( $output, $source,  0, 0, 0, 0,$width, $height,$width,$height);

Use this code for Center of the Image:

$watermark_pos_x = (imagesx($image)/2) - (imagesx($watermark)/2) - 15;
$watermark_pos_y = (imagesy($image)/2) - (imagesy($watermark)/2) - 10;

// merge the source image and the watermark
imagecopy($image, $watermark,  $watermark_pos_x, $watermark_pos_y, 0, 0,imagesx($watermark), imagesy($watermark));