# How to resize overlay image by ratio and with relative position it from the right?

Tags: imagemagick

Let's start with a background and an overlay image:

```
magick convert -size 500x500! xc:red  background.jpg    # make a big red background
magick convert -size 100x100! xc:blue overlay.jpg       # make a smaller blue overlay
```

To [composite from right side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26236026/3416774) I can use

```
$geom=magick convert overlay.jpg -print "+%[fx:w+50]+0" null:
magick convert background.jpg overlay.jpg -gravity northeast -geometry $geom -composite output.jpg
```

[image]

However, in my real project, I need to run this with various background images, whose sizes are also various. I would like the overlay to use relative size to the background instead of absolute size.

To [overlaying a watermark/logo with relative dimentions](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?p=155092&sid=5972139a23a7d3fd865ff78013694cc3#p155092), I can use:

```
magick background.jpg overlay.jpg -resize %[fx:t?u.w*0.9:u.w]x%[fx:t?u.h*0.9:u.h] -gravity northease -composite output.jpg
```

To resize overlay image by ratio and with relative position it from the right, I try:

```
magick background.jpg overlay.jpg -resize %[fx:t?u.w*0.1:u.w]x%[fx:t?u.h*0.1:u.h] -gravity northeast -geometry +[fx:t?u.w*0.1:u.w]+[fx:t?u.h*0.1:u.h] -composite output.jpg
```

But it says:
`magick.exe: invalid argument for option '-geometry' '+[fx:t?u.w*0.1:u.w]+[fx:t?u.h*0.1:u.h]' at CLI arg 7 @ error/operation.c/CLISimpleOperatorImage/2522.`

The documentation for [`geometry`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry) doesn't seem to talk about this. Do you know why?

I'm using v7 on Windows

Answer (score 0):

I miss the `%`. Correct code:

```
magick .\base.jpg .\logo.png -resize %[fx:t?u.w*0.1:u.w]x%[fx:t?u.h*0.1:u.h] -gravity northeast -geometry +%[fx:t?u.w*0.03:u.w]+%[fx:t?u.w*0.03:u.w] -composite output.png
```

See [Format and Print Image Properties](https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php)

## The reasoning behind the `%[fx:t?u.w*0.9:u.w]`

From [The FX Special Effects Image Operator](https://imagemagick.org/script/fx.php):

```
u: first image in list
v: second image in list
t: index of current image (s) in list
w: width of this image
```

So in plain language, it means that if the image in question is the second image, whose index is one, of which the ternary conditional operator also read as true, then resize it to 90% width of the first image, else do no resize. Or else `-resize` option will [apply to each images in an image sequence](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#operator) (i.e. all input images before it, but not after it).